# SwiftUI Combine function -> any publisher return type

Tags: swiftui, combine

```
func reqAuth(serviceParams: AuthServiceParams) -> AnyPublisher<AuthResponse, Error> {
    
    var subject = PassthroughSubject<Any,Error>()
    
    AlamofireService.auth(serviceParams: serviceParams).responseObject { (response : DataResponse<AuthResponse>) in
        
        if (response.error != nil ) {
            
            print("❌⭕️❌ Auth login hatalı bir dönüş aldı sorun var.")
            
            subject.send(response.error!)
            
            
            return
            
        } else {
            
            if let data = response.result.value {
                guard let token = data.data?.token else {
                 print("TOKEN BULUNAMADI")
                let authResponse = AuthResponse(
                result: "fault",
                success: false,
                data: nil,
                message: "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı",
                errCode: "E0000"
               )
                    subject.send(response)
                    return
                
                
                
            }
                print("AuthLogin Token ------->   \(token)")
                ApplicationVariables.token = token
                ApplicationVariables.customer = data.data?.customer
                ApplicationVariables.config = data.data?.store?.config
                ApplicationVariables.logo = data.data?.store?.logo
                subject.send(data)
            }else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "Bir sorun oluştu. Lütfen yöneticinize başvurunuz.", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
                subject.send(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code base , the problem is I couldn't find the right return , what should I return in this function or how ? I tried subject.eraseToAnyPublisher() but its not match with return type.

Answer (score 1):

In line with declaring subject `var subject = PassthroughSubject<Any,Error>()`
change `Output` generic to `AuthResponse`

You should send errors as errors rather than values, you can send error with `subject.send(completion: .failure(#Error#))`.

`subject.send(#Output#)` sends a value

fixed code:

```
func reqAuth(serviceParams: AuthServiceParams) -> AnyPublisher<AuthResponse, Error> {

  var subject = PassthroughSubject<AuthResponse, Error>()

  AlamofireService.auth(serviceParams: serviceParams).responseObject { (response : DataResponse<AuthResponse>) in

    guard response.error == nil else {

      print("❌⭕️❌ Auth login hatalı bir dönüş aldı sorun var.")

      subject.send(completion: .failure(response.error!))

      return
    }

    if let data = response.result.value {
      guard let token = data.data?.token else {
        print("TOKEN BULUNAMADI")
        let authResponse = AuthResponse(
          result: "fault",
          success: false,
          data: nil,
          message: "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı",
          errCode: "E0000"
        )
        subject.send(response)
        return
      }

      print("AuthLogin Token ------->   \(token)")
      ApplicationVariables.token = token
      ApplicationVariables.customer = data.data?.customer
      ApplicationVariables.config = data.data?.store?.config
      ApplicationVariables.logo = data.data?.store?.logo
      subject.send(data)
    } else {
      let error = NSError(domain: "Bir sorun oluştu. Lütfen yöneticinize başvurunuz.", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
      subject.send(completion: .failure(error))
    }
  }
}
```